# MySQL insert of binary columns

Tags: mysql

I communicate with MySQL server version 5.0.45 via MySQL Query Browser 1.2.14

Have column of type *binary(6)*.

```
CREATE TABLE  `test` (
  `tid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `h` binary(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tid`),
  KEY `idx1` (`h`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

After query

```
INSERT INTO test(h) VALUES(X'AABBCCDDEEFF');
```

I see in the *h* field of added row corrupted value like

```
D0 84 C2 BB D0 9C
```

Seems that mysql treated binary value as a string and stored it according to some charset. But then why does it ignore *binary* column type and X'...' notation of value to insert?
Am I doing wrong or MySQL is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use [`HEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_hex)?

```sql
SELECT HEX(h) FROM test;
```

Will give you:

```
|       HEX(H) |
|--------------|
| AABBCCDDEEFF |
```

Now if you want to treat a hexadecimal value as a number you need to use `CAST(h AS UNSIGNED)`.

```sql
SELECT CAST(X'AABBCCDDEEFF' AS UNSIGNED);
```

Output:

```
| CAST(X'AABBCCDDEEFF' AS UNSIGNED) |
|-----------------------------------|
|                   187723572702975 |
```

By default a hexadecimal value is treated as a string, which most likely exactly what you wanted it to be, judging by the data type that you've chosen. It's just the output that scared you off.

Further reading

- [Hexadecimal Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)